# Android Studio2.1 preview 5 on ubuntu unable to open the projects in

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

When **android studio 2.1 preview 5** on ubuntu 14.04 unable to show the list of projects and unable to open any project, when try to open it shows below exception.

> Exception

```
Can not load Project: java.lang.illegalException:@NotNull method
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use following Step :

**1.** Force stop Android studio from Task Manager

**2.** Clean all cache

**3.** Restart laptop

Comment: @Maheshwar Ligade see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Studio will restart after that try loading the project

Comment: @M Balajivaishnav  I restarted my machine then also i am getting the same error, When I try to invalidate caches / Restart  its not working for me

Comment: Nothing work it just show the same screen,its not restarted

Comment: the error comes from Cache folder so remove all the Android Studio related folders in this path: ~/Library/Caches/ and give a try

Comment: I go back to the android studio2.0 stable version